# Why wont my DropDownListFor populate my id property when I POST?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor

I've got a `DropDownListFor` which displays a list of `Events` for me. I'm trying to `POST` back the `ID` of the selected `event`. The `EventId` is always coming back as `0`. *(Please ignore the mess of no service layer or repositories, it's just a sample project.)*

My Model:

```
public List<SelectListItem> Events { get; set; }

public int EventId { get; set; }
```

My View:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.EventId, Model.Events, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Here is how I am populating `Events` in the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    //Setting up Events for the DropDownListFor
    var events = db.Events.ToList().Select(e => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = e.EventName,
        Value = e.EventId.ToString()
    }).ToList();

    return View(new User {Events = events });
}
```

And in my `POST`:

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "UserId,FirstName,LastName,Age,VehicleMake,VehicleModel,VehicleYear,AreGuestsAttending,TotalGuests")] User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();

            var enrollUserForEvent = new Enrollment
            {
                UserId = user.UserId,
                EventId = user.EventId
            };

            _enrollmentController.Create(enrollUserForEvent);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Event");
        }

        return View(user);
    }
```

I've tried playing around with several different things like:

```
  var eventIdString = user.Events.First(e => e.Selected == true).Value;
  int eventId = Int32.Parse(eventIdString);
```

But in the above scenario `user.Events` is `null`.

After playing around and searching around I cannot find anything on what I may be doing wrong here. Everything else gets posted back just fine so I'm not sure why I'm not getting the `EventId` to come back with everything else. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

```
Bind(Include ="...")
```

You should also include there the `EventId`. If `EventId` misses from this, the `EventId` property of `user` get's it's default value, which is 0. Including also this to your `Bind` statement, then when the `user` model would be created would take the value of `EventId` from the data you POST and the value you post would be set properly.